# Decimal formatter fails to parse to the right form?

Tags: java, decimalformat

Im making a toto app, which should return the Statistics of all games. It should return the win percentage of `team#1, team#2` and `draws` with 2 friction digits.
I tried to do it with the following:

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("##,##");
double firstTeamWinPercentage = firstTeamWinCounter/totalMatches*100;
    double secondTeamWinPercentage = secondTeamWinCounter/totalMatches*100;
    double drawPercentage = drawPercentageCounter/totalMatches*100;

    statistics.setFirstTeamWinPercentage(Double.parseDouble(dec.format(firstTeamWinPercentage)));
    statistics.setSecondTeamWinPrecentage(Double.parseDouble(dec.format(secondTeamWinPercentage)));
    statistics.setDrawPercentage(Double.parseDouble(dec.format(drawPercentage)));
```

However somehow it doesn't parse like it should do. With this method, the Statistics looks like this:
`Statistics:  Team #1 won: 45.0 %, Team #2 won: 29.0 %, draw: 26.0 %`

If I add  `dec.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);`, then the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45,09"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
```

Im using jdk-17. Any ideas why it is thrown like this?
I already tried using `DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("00,00");`
and `DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("##,00");`
They also throw exceptions.

Comment: Please don't **explain** what parts of your code is doing. Give us a [mcve] that contains all relevant pieces of code, and that we ideally can easily compile and run ourselves. And especially in this case, a mcve should be really easy: you only need some variables, and then apply the formatter.

Comment: Okay, noted. Thx

Comment: `.` and `,` in `DecimalFormat` strings **always** denote decimal separator and grouping separator respectively, irrespective of the output language. If you want "12,34" as an output in a locale where , is used as a decimal separator, your format string needs to be `##.##`.

Comment: My Statistics class is made of 3 `doubles`. Which are `firstTeamWinPercent` etc. and these are calculated with their counters. (i.e. `firstTeamWinCounter`) I have to convert back to `doubles` because my `Statistics` class requires a `double` in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to make use of the `DecimalFormat` in order to parse my variables to two digit decimals. However The following sollution works fine aswell:

```
 BigDecimal twoDecimalFirstTeamWinPercentageBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(twoDecimalFirstTeamWinPercentage).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

where

```
twoDecimalFirstTeamWinPercentage
```

is a `double`

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in formatting your double to a string, then parsing it to a double again. Depending on how you generate your string, trailing zeroes will be stripped.

If you require two decimal places, you could use [`String#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)):

```
double d = 1.2;
String s = String.format("Your value = %.2f", d);
System.out.println(s); // Your value = 1.20
```

The crucial part is missing from your question: how is `Statistics#toString` implemented? (Or whichever method generates the string output for your statistics class.

Comment: the toString() method for Statistics is returning doubles, so thats why I wanted to format it as a String. Basically the `firstTeamWinPercentage`,`secondTeamWinPercentage `,`drawPercentage` had way too many decimals, so I wanted to parse it to a String, thus getting rid of too many decimals. After that I wanted to parse (the now formatted String) back to a double. Sorry if the comment was not so professional, Im a beginner.

Comment: @Mate23 `double` cannot precisely represent all (real) numbers, it is only an approximation. Use `BigDecimal` if you need arbitrary precision (as you have noted in your answer). Use the String-based constructor to avoid any loss of precision when converting to/from `double`. Nevertheless, using the proper format specifier(s), such as `%.2f`, will give you what you need (max 2 decimals places in your output).